# How to execute file I'm editing in Vi(m)

Tags: vim, exec

How to execute file that I'm editing in Vi(m) and get output in split window (like in SciTE)?

Of course I could execute it like that:

```
:!scriptname
```

But is it posible to avoid writing script name and how to get output in split window instead just bottom of the screen?

Comment: :!% will let you avoid writing 'scriptname'.  The solutions below are better, but I thought I'd mention this in case you decide :!% is good enough.

Comment: Another note, you can use %:p (instead of just %) to refer to the current file's absolute path. This might be necessary if your current directory is somewhere else.

Comment: to run ruby scripts :!ruby % will do the trick

Comment: @andy :!%:p also resolves not having the directory being in the $PATH

Comment: And `:!"%:p"` to cope with whitespace.

Comment: technically the answer to the title (without splitscreen) is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15449591/vim-execute-current-file ..ie :`nnoremap <F5> :!%:p<Enter>` or `nnoremap <F5> :!clear && %:p<Enter>` use inoremap to work in insert mode too.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

There is the `make` command. It runs the command set in the `makeprg` option. Use `%` as a placeholder for the current file name. For example, if you were editing a python script:

```
:set makeprg=python\ %
```

Yes, you need to escape the space. After this you can simply run:

```
:make
```

If you wish, you can set the `autowrite` option and it will save automatically before running the `makeprg`:

```
:set autowrite
```

This solves the execute part. Don't know any way of getting that output into a split window that doesn't involve redirection to file.

Comment: Actually, your solution does get the output to a split window.  Use `:copen` to open up the "error list" produced by running `:make`.in its own window.  Unfortunately, to get the output to be formatted properly, some finagling of the `errorformat` option is necessary.  Otherwise output will be presumed to be of the format gcc puts out.

Comment: You're damn sure about "finagling" errorformat. It look like some perl code I've seen...

Comment: This facility is available for 'make' of project from vim (gives vim the IDE like capability). Brian Carper's solution (`:let f=expand("%")|vnew|execute '.!ruby "' . f . '"'`) though looks cryptic, works exactly as asked by author of the question.

Answer (score 30):

To access the current buffer's filename, use `%`.  To get it into a variable you can use the `expand()` function.  To open a new window with a new buffer, use `:new` or `:vnew`.  To pipe the output from a command into the current buffer, use `:.!` .    Putting it all together:

```
:let f=expand("%")|vnew|execute '.!ruby "' . f . '"'
```

obviously replacing `ruby` with whatever command you want.  I used `execute` so I could surround the filename with quotation marks, so it'll work if the filename has spaces in it.

Comment: @baboonWorksFine Use  `:command! R let f=expand("%")|vnew|execute '.!ruby "' . f . '"'` to be able to just use `:R` to execute his command

Comment: Would it be possible to make this run even with scripts that require user input while executing?

Answer (score 25):

Vim has `!` ("bang") command which executes shell command directly from VIM window. Moreover it allows launching sequence of commands that are connected with pipe and read stdout.

For example:

```
! node %
```

is equivalent to opening command prompt window and launching commands:

```
cd my_current_directory 
node my_current_file
```

See ["Vim tips: Working with external commands"](https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/442419-vim-tips-working-with-external-commands) for details.

Answer (score 11):

I have a shortcut for that in my vimrc:

```
nmap <F6> :w<CR>:silent !chmod 755 %<CR>:silent !./% > .tmp.xyz<CR>
     \ :tabnew<CR>:r .tmp.xyz<CR>:silent !rm .tmp.xyz<CR>:redraw!<CR>
```

This writes the current buffer, makes the current file executable (unix only), executes it (unix only) and redirects the output to .tmp.xyz, then creates a new tab, reads the file and then deletes it.

Breaking it down:

```
:w<CR>                             write current buffer
:silent !chmod 755 %<CR>           make file executable
:silent !./% > .tmp.xyz<CR>        execute file, redirect output
:tabnew<CR>                        new tab
:r .tmp.xyz<CR>                    read file in new tab
:silent !rm .tmp.xyz<CR>           remove file
:redraw!<CR>                       in terminal mode, vim get scrambled
                                   this fixes it
```

Comment: I liked your solution a lot, and after a while of using it, I felt that it could be improved. So here's my take on it: `:w<CR>:silent !chmod +x %:p<CR>:silent !%:p 2>&1 | tee ~/.vim/output<CR>:split ~/.vim/output<CR>:redraw!<CR>` — this redirects both the stdout and stderr to the temp file, and before doing so, it prints everything to stdout, so if a script takes long to run you actually see it working. Also, it's directory-independent (I was getting errors when opening files by their absolute path). It does not run scripts interactively, however, and I haven't found a way to make it so.

Comment: fyi -- on @Cyril 's solution, I had to escape the pipe symbol: | -> \|

Answer (score 7):

Vim 8 has an interactive terminal built in. To run the current bash script in a split pane:

```
:terminal bash %
```

or for short

```
:ter bash %
```

`%` expands to the current file name.

From `:help terminal`:

```
The terminal feature is optional, use this to check if your Vim has it:
    echo has('terminal')
If the result is "1" you have it.
```

Answer (score 4):

For Shell script I've used

```
:set makeprg=%

:make
```

Answer (score 1):

I use a slightly more intrusive mechanism through maps:

```
map ;e :w<CR>:exe ":!python " . getreg("%") . "" <CR>
```

Just makes it so I don't have to save, then go.  Just go.

Comment: If you set the autowrite option, you can run :make and it... auto saves before.

Answer (score 1):

You can use vim's plugin [bexec](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1788). To my knowledge the latest version is 0.5.

Then:

```
$ mkdir -p ~/.vim/plugin
$ mv bexec-0.5.vba ~/.vim/plugin
$ vim ~/.vim/plugin/bexec-0.5.vba
```

Inside vim itself while editing the .vba file do:

```
:so %
```

Some output will show up letting you know that **bexec.vim** has been written as well as documentation, etc..

Now, you can test it by opening your (whatever language script that has an #! interpreter working properly) in vim and run

```
:Bexec
```

Note: I wanted the split to be vertical rather than horizontal, so I did:

```
$ grep -i -n split ~/.vim/plugin/bexec.vim | grep -i hor
102:    let bexec_splitdir = "hor" " hor|ver
261:        exec {"ver":"vsp", "hor":"sp"}[g:bexec_splitdir]
```

and changed the value of  from "hor" to "ver"..

I know it's an old question, but I hope this can help someone out there. I have been running in the same issue while taking Coursera's Startup Engineering course where professor Palaji uses Emacs and I don't like Emacs..

Comment: You should change preference related settings in your local .vimrc. bexec offers "let bexec_splitdir='hor'" setting which can do so without modifying the plugin code.

Answer (score 1):

Just use colon and exclamatory mark as shown below

> :!< script_name>

Answer (score 0):

Based on @SethKriticos and @Cyril answers I now use the following:

```
function! Setup_ExecNDisplay()
  execute "w"
  execute "silent !chmod +x %:p"
  let n=expand('%:t')
  execute "silent !%:p 2>&1 | tee ~/.vim/output_".n
  " I prefer vsplit
  "execute "split ~/.vim/output_".n
  execute "vsplit ~/.vim/output_".n
  execute "redraw!"
  set autoread
endfunction

function! ExecNDisplay()
  execute "w"
  let n=expand('%:t')
  execute "silent !%:p 2>&1 | tee ~/.vim/output_".n
  " I use set autoread
  "execute "1 . 'wincmd e'"
endfunction

:nmap <F9> :call Setup_ExecNDisplay()<CR>
:nmap <F2> :call ExecNDisplay()<CR>
```

Use F9 to setup the new window and F2 to execute your script and tee to your output file.

I also added the script name to the output file name, so that you can use this for multiple scripts at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

@xorpaul

I was looking for this script (python/Windows) for quite some time. As there is no "tee" in Windows I changed it to:

```
function! Setup_ExecNDisplay()
  execute "w"
  let n=expand('%:t')
  execute "silent ! python % > d:\\temp\\output_".n ." 2>&1"
  execute "vsplit d:\\temp\\output_".n
  execute "redraw!"
  set autoread
endfunction

function! ExecNDisplay()
  execute "w"
  let n=expand('%:t')
  execute "silent ! python % > d:\\temp\\output_".n . " 2>&1"
endfunction

:nmap <F9> :call Setup_ExecNDisplay()<CR>
:nmap <F2> :call ExecNDisplay()<CR>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `.vimrc` you can paste this function

```
function! s:ExecuteInShell(command)
  let command = join(map(split(a:command), 'expand(v:val)'))
  let winnr = bufwinnr('^' . command . '$')
  silent! execute ':w'
  silent! execute  winnr < 0 ? 'vnew ' . fnameescape(command) : winnr . 'wincmd w'
  setlocal buftype=nowrite bufhidden=wipe nobuflisted noswapfile nowrap number
  silent! execute 'silent %!'. command
  silent! redraw
  silent! execute 'au BufUnload <buffer> execute bufwinnr(' . bufnr('#') . ') . ''wincmd w'''
  silent! execute 'nnoremap <silent> <buffer> <LocalLeader>r :call <SID>ExecuteInShell(''' . command . ''')<CR>'
  silent! execute 'wincmd w'
  " echo 'Shell command ' . command . ' executed.'
endfunction
command! -complete=shellcmd -nargs=+ Shell call s:ExecuteInShell(<q-args>)
cabbrev shell Shell
```

After that, in `vim` run command `:shell python ~/p.py` as example. And you will get the output in splitted window.
+ After changes in `p.py` as example you will run the same command again, this function will not create new window again, it will display the result in the previous(same) splitted window.

Comment: This is awesome, thank you! How might you change it to rerun when the buffer is written again?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend the plugin [quickrun](https://vimawesome.com/plugin/vim-quickrun). It's fast and simple to configure. Here's a little demonstration:
[image]