# Vim: execute current file?

Tags: vim

If I have a file with a shebang line (e.g. `#!/bin/bash`) open in Vim and the file has execute permissions (i.e. `chmod +x`) I know I can type this to execute it without leaving the editor:

```
:! %:p
```

- `:` for command mode
- `!` to run a shell command
- `%` to refer to the file in the current buffer
- `:p` to use the full path of the current file

Is there a shorter shortcut for this frequent task?

e.g. there is a `ZZ` shortcut for `:wq`, etc.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

```
:!%:p
```

,without the spaces, is shorter.

If you want an even shorter shortcut, you can create a custom mapping:

```
nnoremap <F9> :!%:p
```

or the more "mnemonic":

```
nnoremap <leader>r :!%:p
```

Comment: use nnoremap <F9> :!%:p<Enter> to allevate the burden of pressing Enter each time.

Comment: use `nnoremap <F9> :!%:p<Enter><Enter>` to also skip `Press ENTER or type command to continue` after the script execution

Comment: `nnoremap <F9> :!%:p<Enter><Enter>` runs the code and returns to vim immediately. Use single Enter `nnoremap <F9> :!%:p<Enter>` to keep the output screen

Comment: [About `nnoremap`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18917038). Also note that this won't handle file names with spaces properly, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46348040/5267751) below.

Comment: I like having a fresh terminal for every execution so I don't get outputs from previous runs confused with the current one. To do this you can use `nnoremap <F9> :!clear && %:p<Enter>`

Comment: How could I map the action of saving a file and running it to F9? If I put `:w` before the suggested sequence, I get E212.

Comment: If you dont use the `p` you may get the error "shell returned 127"

Comment: fyi, default leader is \  ..use `:echo mapleader` (undefined error if default) or `:let mapleader = ","` (example)

Answer (score 31):

If you haven't set permissions you can run:

```
:! sh %
```

Answer (score 24):

None of the previous answers work if your filename/directory path has spaces in it. Simple fix.

```
:!"%:p"
```

Answer (score 14):

After you've executed that once, a short `:!!` will repeat it.

Answer (score 11):

When starting vi, specify file path explicitly, like this "vi ./blablabla"

```
vi ./yourscript.pl
```

Then start with `!%`

The other variant is to invoke the vi command like this

```
!./%
```

Answer (score 6):

You can add a key mapping to your .vimrc

```
map <F5> :!%
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to execute the current file in vim if there are **spaces** in **file name**

```
:!./"%"
```