# executing current python file in vim creates new file if current time is parsed

Tags: datetime, vim

I am executing python files from vim as described here:
[How to execute file I'm editing in Vi(m)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953398/how-to-execute-file-im-editing-in-vim)

I observe the same behavior on Windows & Linux.
For testing, I moved my .vim so as to avoid other plugins interfering. Then I set:

```
:set makeprg=python\ %
```

Now when I run an example file like this (called mini.py)

```
import datetime

print "hello"

def foo1():
    print "foo"
    print "str: " + str(datetime.datetime.now())
    print "str: " + str(datetime.datetime.now().date())

foo1()
```

Now when I execute

```
:make
"mini.py" 10L, 173C written
:!python mini.py  2>&1| tee /tmp/vew33jl/9
hello
foo
str: 2013-05-07 17:01:47.124149
str: 2013-05-07
"str: 2013-05-07 17" [New File]
(3 of 4): 47.124149
```

vim kind of chokes on the datetime.now output and creates a new file with the current date and instantly displays it.

Is this behavior to be expected?

If I comment out the .now() line (now().date() is not a problem apparently), it works as expected and I more or less see the text output that I'd expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `'makeprg'`, Vim parses the output according to `'errorformat'` to retrieve error messages from the output. Your date output looks conspicuously like a typical error message, and by default, `:make` jumps to the first error location it encounters.

What you can do:

- Use `:make!` (with bang); that will avoid the jump to the first error. Or:
- In addition to setting `'makeprg'`, also clear the `'errorformat'` to avoid that Vim parses the output; unless you're only ever edit Python files with Vim; you should use `:setlocal`, not the global `:set`, and put that into `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/python.vim`:

```
:setlocal makeprg=python\ %
:setlocal errorformat=
```

Comment: so basically I would set: 
au FileType python setlocal makeprg=python\ %
au FileType python setlocal errorformat=

This is equivalent, right?

Comment: Yes, that is equivalent, but my solution scales better for many such settings (but requires `:filetype plugin on`).