# How can the console output using exec be directed to a new vsplit in vimrc?

Tags: vim

I think my question is related to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953398/how-to-execute-file-im-editing-in-vim), but I not sure how to make it work for what I want to do.

In my vimrc I have a this function:

```
func! AutoGo()
   exec "w" 
   exec "!auto-go"
endfunc
```

I want to open a new split window in vim of the output of my exec "!auto-go" command. Something like this:

```
func! AutoGo()
   exec "w" 
   output = exec "!auto-go"
   vsplit output

endfunc
```

I also found this [resource](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/52.html), but I can't get it to work.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: You don't need the `:exec` here, only when you want to interpolate variable contents into the commands.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to execute external command and capture the output in your script, you could use `system()` function.  After you got the command output,
to display the output in split, you could `vnew +{cmd}`

Comment: This is close to what I want, but for some reason, it's opening my file, instead of the output of my script. This is what I tried "new +{system("!auto-go")}" Do you know why its my file rather than my script output?

Comment: try removing the `!` in `system()` @Amozoss

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have the issue of "E492: Not an editor command: system("auto-go")." I guess I had the same issue with "system("!auto-go"), I just had forgotten to reload my vimrc. It seems like it should work because exec "!auto-go" works just fine.